Migratory insertion of alkyl group without alpha hydrogen
I am reffering to the alkyl migratory insertion in $\ce{CO}$ ligand explained
here 
Following is sourced from the same:-

This reaction, migratory insertion of a hydride to a carbonyl, forms a metal "formyl" compound. The "formyl" is the CH=O group attached to the metal. Migratory insertions can also take place with metal alkyls. Metal alkyls are also nucleophilic, just like metal hydrides. The alkyl carbon is usually more electronegative than the attached transition metal, so it has a partial negative charge.

Figure  $4.3.4$: A migratory insertion reaction, this time forming an acyl compound.
In fact, migratory insertion to a carbonyl is actually much more common with alkyl ligands than it is with hydrides. Conceptually, the reactions are very similar. The reason alkyl migrations are much more common has to do with relative bonds strengths in the reactants compared to the products of the reaction.

I believe Agostic interactions are on play in the transition state, the reason why alkyl group is migrated to only cis-CO ligand.
Following is some more info about agostic interactions from ChemLibreTexts

In some metal alkyl complexes, C–H bonds at the α, β, or even farther positions can serve as electron donors to the metal center. This idea is supported by crystallographic evidence and NMR chemical shifts (the donating hydrogens shift to high field). Such interactions are called agostic interactions, and they resemble an “interrupted” transition state for hydride elimination. Alkyl complexes that cannot undergo β-hydride elimination for electronic reasons (high oxidation state, d0 metals) and vinyl complexes commonly exhibit this phenomenon. The fact that β-hydride elimination is slow for d0 metals—agostic interactions are seen instead—suggests that back-donation from a filled metal orbital to the σ*C–H is important for β-hydride elimination. Here’s an interesting, recent-ish review of agostic interactions.


So my question is, what if there is no $\alpha-\ce{H}$ as in $\ce{(CH3)3C}-$ group? would there still be some kind of agostic interactions? would it then migrate? If so, please share the transition state for the same

I don't downvote your question. But I assume it more likely a homework question. You may need to provide your thoughts on the process so that we can correct you or suggest our thinking. Otherwise, this question will be closed.

@MathewMahindaratne The question asks "What if there is no alpha hydrogen like in tertiary butyl group?" It is contrasting with the methyl group shown in the diagram. The diagram also shows a migration of the methyl group to the carbonyl - it's a very long time since I looked at this but memories from 3 decades ago suggest this is a common organometallic reaction type.  The question needs clarity on which "interaction" is being discussed, but as for the tertiary group and the migration I can't see a problem.

@IanBush I thought there is some name like Agostic is, I am removing it

@MathewMahindaratne sorry for the grievances, my edited post should now consider your concerns, thanks

To answer your question you may need a little more understanding on organometallic chemistry and its anatomy. If you look at Ref. 1 which is a review on your concern, you find some insight and states that:

Soon after the discovery of transition metal alkyl compounds, it became clear that the presence of the transition metal imparted properties to the alkyl group that were unprecedented in the normal ambient chemistry of simple organic compounds. For instance, the occurrence of the reversible $\alpha$-elimination process and the ability to extract hydride from the $\beta$-carbon of a transition metal–ethyl compound are two examples of the impact of a transition metal on an alkyl group.

For example, the following figure shows the isomerization of transition metal ethylene hydrides $\bf{1}$ to $\beta/\alpha$-agostic ethyl compounds $\bf{2}$ and $\bf{3}$ via transition states $\bf{TS_I}$ and $\bf{TS_{II}}$ (Ref. 2)

Your diagram shows only $\beta$-agostic interaction:

My understanding of your question is based on your diagram, if  $\beta$-\$\ce{H}$ is absent (like tert-butyl group instead of isopropyl group in first compound in your diagram), would there still be some kind of agostic interactions?
The answer is yes as stated in ChemLibreTexts except you given in the text:

In some metal alkyl complexes, $\ce{C–H}$ bonds at the $\alpha, \beta,$ or even farther positions can serve as electron donors

These interaction is illustrated in following diagram:

Figure 1 of Ref. 1 provides this kind of interaction (pentacyclic). Keep in mind that these interactions are only possible due to the structure of the metal complex, which should allows the close proximity of $\ce{M-H}$ distance. The following diagram illustrates such situation, which allows only $\alpha$-elimination (Ref. 3):

If you are really talking about tert-butyl group directly attached to metal atom, in which there are no hydrogen attached to $\alpha$-carbon, I couldn't find such relevant example(s) in literature. However, if such example exist, there are still $beta$-agostic interactions possible from either of three methyl groups and metal atom.
References:

Recommends reading: Maurice Brookhart, Malcolm L. H. Green, and Gerard Parkin, "Agostic interactions in transition metal compounds,” Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. USA 2007, 104(17), 6908–6914 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.0610747104).
Rong Xu, Günter Klatt, Hubert Wadepohl, and Horst Köppel, "Hydrogen Scrambling in $\ce{[(C5R5)(L)M(H)(C2H4)]+ (M = Co, Rh)}$. Relation of Experimental Kinetic Data to the Barriers of the Elementary Reaction Steps,” Inorg. Chem. 2010, 49(7), 3289–3296 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/ic902276a).
Morteza Karimzadeh-Younjali and Ola F. Wendt, "α- and β-Eliminations in Transition Metal Complexes: Strategies to Cleave Unstrained C−C and C−F Bonds,” Helv. Chim. Acta 2021, 101(11), e2100114 (16 pages) (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1002/hlca.202100114).


wow, your answer is so beautiful. yes i am fairly new to this topic and i have only been accustomed of some simple mechanisms so far. so i am still trying to understand the $\alpha$ elimination of fluorine

I got the whole text now, finally, and thanks for the nickelacycle, it was new to me. It would be also nice if you could add the T.S for migration of any group, say $\ce{(CH3)3C}-$ into the $\ce{CO}$ ligand. Also you mistyped  $\beta-\ce{H}$, "excerpt" as "except" and $\beta$ as $beta$ in the following order.

is there any limit for these agostic interactions? since you included $\gamma-$interactions as well

Mostly steric effects as size of other ligands (read ref. 1). Also reaction conditions and availability of $\mathrm{d}$-orbitals of the metal play a role too.
